# What came out of the team up with Google AI for the rpi 4?

Tags: pi-4

I remember back in 2017 I had read several blog articles such as [this one](https://www.freelancinggig.com/blog/2017/02/13/raspberry-pi-4-google-adding-ai-tools-raspberry-pi/) where it was mentioned that the rpi foundation had teamed up with Google and that we could expect Google AI for the raspberry pi 4.

From the reviews I have read about the rpi 4, there is no mention of anything special about Google tools. So I wonder, what came out of the alliance with Google? Is there any software related to Google AI that is installed by default that wasn't installed in the raspberry pi 3? No special voice recognition for example?

Comment: Google has come out with its own line of dev-boards, including at least one that matches the Pi model 2/3 footprint -- however, they also include diminutive [TPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_processing_unit).  They're intended for developing tensorboard edge node capable devices, so AI centric: https://insidehpc.com/2019/03/announcing-googles-new-tpu-dev-board-for-machine-learning-on-the-edge/ Note that the standard google speech APIs can be used on any model of pi as far as I am aware -- most of it is just accessing their network which does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: @goldilocks that could be posted as an answer, I suppose.